# Prove simple inequality

Tags: inequality

Prove that for any $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ the following inequality holds true:
$$a^2+b^2+16\geq ab+4a+4b$$
I tried some reductions, but with no success. Any hint appreciable! Thanks in advance.

Comment: $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ac$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$4a^2+4b^2+64-4ab-16a-16b=(a+b-8)^2+3(a-b)^2$$